How to disconnect a user from coova-chilli as a system administrator?
I have a captive portal that works with coova-chilli. I also have an admin panel that can create user, edit, delete. It should also be able to disconnect the active user user. I'm using the ChilliLibrary.js library, but I can't find a function that implements this.
There is a logoff function, but this function is only for the main user, so that he himself logs out of the system
